# win7 task scheduler say running powershell script. task manager has no activity

Tags: powershell, task, scheduler, taskmanager

I am in administrative group and have a powershell script that is scheduled as a Basic Task to run for the first time in Win 7 using Task Scheduler.

In Task Scheduler, the Status says it is running.  If I run it manually, it would take ~30 minutes.

However, while the Task Scheduler say it is running, the Task manager has nothing from running powershell script at all.

Comment: Can you show us how you have task scheduler configured for you script